# SSIS not able to run package in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, visual-studio-2019

It's very simple package, running fine when executed via visual studio. From the report I get:

[image]

- Visual Studio 2019 Community
- SQL2019CTP3.1

In the connection manager I am using windows authentication. The package has the following structure:

- OLE DB source - simple T-SQL statement
- OLE DB destination - create table and insert the result of the statement

Can anyone tell what can cause this error? I find some topics telling this is a security issue, but not sure what kind of access I need to grant and to whom.

As I said, when I hit the `execute` button in the context of Visual studio the package and execute, a table is created in the destination database and records are inserted.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You mentioned the package runs fine from VS but not how it is run when the errors occur. Add that detail to your question. The security context will be different (e.g. when run under SQL Server Agent service account) and that account will of course need permissions on the resources used (database, file system).

Comment: I've never found that windows authentication works properly with SSIS, especially if it has to reach to another server to do it's work.  Try setting it up with SQL Authentication.  But as Dan says, it smells like an authentication issue.  Especially if it doesn't pass the validation step (which tests connections to resources as best it can)

Comment: @DanGuzman I am working on virtual machine - both the visual studio and the SQL server are there.The `NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT` is `sysadmin` already. I have added full access to this account to the folder where the visual studio project is saved. Nothing change.

Comment: @gotqn, note that the create table in an OLE DB destination is only a design-time function and doesn't create a table during execution. Not saying that's the issue, just mentioning for awareness. Although security is a common issue when it works from VS but not a job, that doesn't seem to be the issue here. See if you have more details about the underlying cause of the error by viewing all messages instead of just errors.

Comment: @DanGuzman It's a kind of strange - the caller in the report is the administrator, so it should not be security issue. Could you tell if the posted details are what you referred as  `viewing all messages`?

Comment: @gotqn, no, that report looks to be the just the error context. Try Reports-->Standard Reports-->All Executions. On a listed Failed execution, click the All Messages link to see the detail messages for the failed execution, which might provide more information about the underlying cause.